# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the Close Search button in File Explorer on Windows 10?

Tags: file, search, keyboard, shortcut, explorer

Has anyone found a keyboard shortcut for the Close Search button in File Explorer on Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

Use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd> from the File Explorer window.

Answer (score 1):

Try: Alt + Left-Arrow

The Alt+J,X doesn't work on my Windows 11 machine.

PS: Alt + Right-Arrow takes you back to the search.

So, you can page through history by using Alt + Left/right-arrow keys.